# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'enemyhp' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm honestly really not sure what the problem is.What I am trying to do is subtract attackdmg from enemyhp. As far as I know, it's all correct. I keep getting the error with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/95bd63b8a3cf1ead/main.py", line 71, in <module>
    attack()
  File "/tmp/sessions/95bd63b8a3cf1ead/main.py", line 46, in attack
    enemyhp = enemyhp - attackdmg
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'enemyhp' referenced before assignment
```

I'm quite new to python so yeah sorry

```
import sys,time,random
global enemyhp
global playerhp


print("""
░░ ▄▄ ▒█▀▀█ ▒█▀▀█ ▒█▀▀█ 　 ▀▀█▀▀ ▒█░▒█ ▀█▀ ▒█▄░▒█ ▒█▀▀█ ▒█▀▀▀█ ▄▄ ░░ 
▀▀ ▄▄ ▒█▄▄▀ ▒█▄▄█ ▒█░▄▄ 　 ░▒█░░ ▒█▀▀█ ▒█░ ▒█▒█▒█ ▒█░▄▄ ▒█░░▒█ ▄▄ ▀▀ 
░░ ░░ ▒█░▒█ ▒█░░░ ▒█▄▄█ 　 ░▒█░░ ▒█░▒█ ▄█▄ ▒█░░▀█ ▒█▄▄█ ▒█▄▄▄█ ░░ ░░ 

                RPG BATTLE THINGY-WINGO

""")

monstertypes = ["BATTY McBATFACE", "SKELETON", "BOSS BAT", "SUPER SKELETON"]
playerhp = 100

#set ID of the attacker
monstername = random.choice(monstertypes)
if monstername == "BATTY McBATFACE":
    enemyhp = 10
elif monstername == "SKELETON":
    enemyhp = 25
elif monstername == "BOSS BAT":
    enemyhp = 50
elif monstername == "SUPER SKELETON":
    enemyhp = 80


typing_speed = 50 #wpm
def slow_type(t, d):
    for l in t:
        sys.stdout.write(l)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if d == "":
          d = 1
        time.sleep(d / 10)
    print("")


def attack():
    print("You attack the", monstername + "!")
    attackdmg = random.randint(5, 20)
    time.sleep(1)
    if not random.randint(1, 4) == 4:
        enemyhp = enemyhp - attackdmg
        if attackdmg >= 15:
            slow_type("THWACK!", 0.5)
            print(attackdmg, "HP of critical damage to the", monstername + "!")
        elif attackdmg >= enemyhp:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            slow_type("KAPOW!", 0.5)
            print(attackdmg, "HP of mortal damage to the", monstername + "!")
        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print(attackdmg, "HP of damage to the", monstername + "!")

    else:
        print("The attack missed!")


approachmsg = ["drew near!", "is in the way!" "attacks!", "approaches...", "wants to fight!", "bumped into you!"]
print(monstername, random.choice(approachmsg))
fighting = True

while fighting:
    print("Do you Fight or Run?")
    battlecommand = input()

    if battlecommand == "Fight" or battlecommand == "fight":
        attack()
    elif battlecommand == "Run" or battlecommand == "run":
        canrun = random.choice([True, False])
        slow_type(". . .", 5)
        if canrun:

            fighting = False
        else:
            print("couldn't get away...")
    else:
      print("please type a valid command!")
if playerhp < 1:
    print("""
█▀▀▀ █▀▀█ █▀▄▀█ █▀▀   █▀▀█ ▀█░█▀ █▀▀ █▀▀█
█░▀█ █▄▄█ █░▀░█ █▀▀   █░░█ ░█▄█░ █▀▀ █▄▄▀
▀▀▀▀ ▀░░▀ ▀░░░▀ ▀▀▀   ▀▀▀▀ ░░▀░░ ▀▀▀ ▀░▀▀
    """)
else:
  slow_type("you escaped!", 0.2)
```

It's supposed to just take attackdmg away from enemyhp, but I'm really not sure why it errors this way.

Comment: Global variables don't work like that in python! Define the variable outside of scope. Modify the variable in-scope by using the Global keyword.

Comment: Please take the time to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might even discover the issue in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Using global variables has a touch of "bad style" ... you need to tell python that you mean to modify the *global* `enemyhp`:

```
der attack():
    global enemyhp  # you want to modify the global one
    # ... rest of code...
```

if you leave it out it looks for `enemyhp` in local function scope and can not find it : hence "used before declared".

Reading globals is fine, you just can no modify them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify that you are working with global variable inside function.

Replace following line

```
enemyhp = enemyhp - attackdmg
```

with

```
global enemyhp
enemyhp = enemyhp - attackdmg
```